# How to drop all scheduler events in MySQL 5.6?

Tags: mysql-5.6, jobs

In MySQL 5.6 is there a way to drop all scheduler events with an administrative command or do I have to go through them one by one with DROP EVENT [IF EXISTS] event_name?

Comment: I think you have to use the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`EVENTS` table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-table.html) to gather all the active events and then construct and run the `DROP EVENT` statements.

Comment: It looks like this is the only way, so it's scripting time. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can disable them via the following command:

```
set GLOBAL event_scheduler=0;
```

or dropping them one by one using the command:

```
DROP EVENT [IF EXISTS] event_name;
```